# Run pgr_createTopology() on custom geometry(linestring) table

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

How could I create a topology for a custom generated geometry table having just `the_geom` geometry(linestring) column? Because `pgr_createTopolgy()` asks for the `gid` column also for a given table, which is not something like primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that `gid` is not a primary key?
Because the `pgr_createTopology` function requires a serial ID column as argument (the default column name is `id`), you could simply add it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD column id serial;
```

Is there a reason, why this is not possible in your case?

Comment: My bad. There was some inconsistency in my `the_geom` column's SRID. Indeed `pgr_createTopology` simply asks for `geometry column` and `serial ID column` and is working just fine. Thanks.